# Map HATEOAS links to actual API links

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hal-json

I'm trying to implement a HATEOAS Rest Client using Spring Boot.

Right now, I'm stuck in a point where I need to convert HATEOAS into an actual API URI.

If I post a new object of type Customer like:

```
{
    "name": "Frank",
    "address": "http://localhost:8080/address/23"
}
```

And then I retrieved with a request to http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1`, HATEOAS gives me something like

```
{
    "name": Frank,
    "_links": {
        "address": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address"
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to convert a link of the form of `http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address` to an API call like `http://localhost:8080/api/address/23` ?

Comment: does `http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address` and `http://localhost:8080/api/address/23` get you the same resources ? After looking at the API endpoints it doesn't seem like that

Comment: @rdj7 yea, `http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address' is the way HATEOAS points you to `http://localhost:8080/api/address/23`

Comment: ok, I think question is little unclear to me, when you do GET request for `http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address` then in the response under the `links` part you want to give `http://localhost:8080/api/address/23` link

Comment: @rjd7 I've updated the question.

Comment: Spring HATEOAS doesn't add links. What other library do you use? Spring Data REST? And how does the `Customer` class look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you see what HATEOS returns after you say,

`GET:   http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1`

is

```
{
"name": Frank,
"_links": {
    "address": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

According to  [Understanding HATEOS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS),

```
It's possible to build more complex relationships. With HATEOAS, the output makes it
easy to glean how to interact with the service without looking up a specification or 
other external document
```

which means,

after you have received resource details with

`http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1` 
what other operations are possible with the received resource those will be shown for easier/click thru access to your service/application,

here in this case HATEOS could find a link `http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/address` that was accessible once you have `customer/1` and from there if you want then without going anywhere else `customer/1` 's address could be found with `/customer/1/address`.

Similarly if you have `/customer/1`'s `occupation` details then there would be another link below `address` link called `http://localhost:8080/api/customer/1/occupation`.

So if `address` is dependent on `customer` i.e. there can be no `address` without `customer` then your API endpoint has to be `/api/customer/1/address` and not directly `/api/address/23`.

However, after understanding these standards and logic behind HATEOS's such responses if you still want to go with your own links that may not align with HATEOS's logic you can use,

[Link Object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/LinkBuilder.html) provided by `LinkBuilder` interface of HATEOS.

Example:
With object of type `Customer` like:

```
Customer c = new Customer( /*parameters*/ );

Link link= linkTo(AnyController.class).slash("address").slash(addressId);
    customer.add(link); 

//considering you want to add link `http://localhost:8080/api/address/23` and `23 is your addressID`.
```

Also you can create a list of Links and keep adding many such links to that list and then add that list to your object.

Hope this helps you !